# Is there a function to help format my legend from numeric to names and a code to remove major and minor grid lines within the ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I managed to get the type of plot that I want, but fail to format my legend to male and female instead of 1 and 2. I have previously managed to achieve a clean plot without the grid lines within the plot with the same command that I now fail on

[image]

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)
mydata <- factor(format(seq(as.Date('2020-01-01'), length.out=12, by='1 month'),'%b'),
             levels = format(seq(as.Date('2020-01-01'), length.out=12, by='1 month'),'%b'),
             ordered = T)

Male <- c(25, 17, 21, 49, 41, 75, 94, 94, 50, 38, 26, 55)
Female <- c(34, 25, 45, 86, 87, 12, 12, 10, 10, 96, 63, 68)

#Create data
df <- data.frame(mydata, Male, Female)
#Melt
df.melted <- melt(df,id.vars = 'mydata')

#plot
ggplot(df.melted,aes(x=factor(mydata),y=value,color=variable,group=variable))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_line()+
  scale_color_manual(labels=c(1:2),values = c('blue','red'))+
  xlab('Months')+ylab('Number of males and females')+

scale_fill_distiller(name=expression(Entrant), 
  labels = parse(text=c("Male","Female")) +

theme_bw()
theme(axis.line=element_line(colour="black"),
       panel.grid.major=element_blank(),
       panel.grid.minor=element_blank(),
       panel.border=element_blank(),
       panel.background=element_blank())
```

Comment: Drop `labels=c(1:2)` in `scale_color_manual`.

Comment: Your code works for me, there are no grid lines if you just format your code correctly, i.e. add another bracket after ````scale_fill_distiller(name=expression(Entrant), 
  labels = parse(text=c("Male","Female")))```` and add ````theme(axis.line=element_line(colour="black"), panel.grid.major=element_blank(), panel.grid.minor=element_blank(), panel.border=element_blank(), panel.background=element_blank())```` with a +.

Comment: It works, thanks. But I still want to change the legend label from variable to gender.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your code considerably and get the desired result:

```r
ggplot(df.melted, aes(x = mydata, y = value, color = variable, group = variable)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line() +
  scale_color_manual(values = c('blue','red')) +
  xlab('Months') + 
  ylab('Number of males and females') +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]